# How do I reach this elevated area on the northeast coast of the Lavi Sandbar?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

In the Cadensia Region, there is an elevated area on the northeast coast of the Lavi Sandbar I can't figure out how to reach. The area is northeast of the Named Grave for Jealous Mizraile and southwest of Hermit's Inlet, has two ether channels and one point of interest marked on my map, and has no visible climbing points.

How do I reach this elevated area?

[image: Image of elevated area]

[image: Map showing area location]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, you cannot access this location yet. That area, known as [Place of Heroes Past](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/Place_of_Heroes_Past), cannot be accessed until Chapter 7.

> The Place of Heroes Past (Japanese: 英霊の遺跡, Eirei no Iseki) is a Landmark in Xenoblade Chronicles 3, located on Lavi Sandbar in Erythia Sea. It is the ruins of the Vault of Heroes from the Spirit Crucible Elpys.
>  **It becomes accessible after the party enters Origin for the first time.**
>  
>  <sub>Emphasis my own</sub>

According to [this](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/357204-xenoblade-chronicles-3/80117013) Gamefaq post,

> the landscape is altered after a specific battle, resulting in this area being unlocked